# ServiceWorker registration failed error show after convert the server into Https

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

This is the code of where register the service worker file

```
window.addEventListener('load', async e => {

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {
        scope: '.' // <--- THIS BIT IS REQUIRED
    }).then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  }
});
```

sw.js code

```
const staticAssets = [
'./',
'./app.js',
'./assets/css/style.css',
'./assets/images/banner1.jpg',
'./assets/images/banner2.jpg',
'./assets/images/banner3.jpg'
];


 self.addEventListener('install', async event => {
  const cache = await caches.open('game-static');
  cache.addAll(staticAssets);
  //console.log('install');
});

 self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // it can be empty if you just want to get rid of that error
 });
```

This error is being logged  in console after the server is converted to Https:

> ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException

Comment: can you access your service worker file at the given location? (~/sw.js)

Comment: yes I can access the service worker file

Comment: please attach your sw.js code - it may have some errors. also, if you think sw.js is ok, try running it on a different browser.